# PEVerify Warning Parameter out of Sequence

Tags: .net, reflection.emit, cil, peverify

I've built an assembly using Reflection.Emit. Running PEVerify returns 214 warnings of the same type:

```
[MD]: Warning: Parameter out of sequence (parameter: 1; seq.num: 1). [token:0x06000171]
```

Unfortunately there isn't much documentation around these sort of issues.

I'm guessing because it's a metadata warning it's something to do with a method name, argument name, class name, method signature, or similar. The only way to relate this back to my code is the number of warnings which is what I'm going to try and go on.

Any help or insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was through the number of errors what were happening. I was using a framework (RunSharp) and accessing the same argument to my method twice. RunSharp doesn't seem to handle this well.